# Wammu configuration on Ubuntu 3G modem Huawei E1550

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, linux-device-driver

I'm try to configure Wammu / gammu ( http://wammu.eu/ ) to use it on my Ubuntu 12.04 but got error message "You don't have permission for /dev/ttyUSB1 device! Maybe you need to be member of dialout group."

From Wammu log :

```
Fri 2013/09/13 14:54:57: [System error - open in serial_open, 13, "Permission denied"]
Fri 2013/09/13 14:54:57: Init:GSM_TryGetModel failed with error DEVICENOPERMISSION[6]:
Error opening device, you don't have permissions.
```

after I add `sudo chown :user /dev/ttyUSB1` problem disappear but still can't connect to the device.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is your user and group didn't have permission to access you device.
you must change permission for user and group. 
If wanna easy change user and group at /etc/init.d/gammu-smsd to root.

```
user="root"
group="root"
bin="/usr/local/bin/gammu-smsd"
configfile="/etc/gammu-smsdrc"
pidfile="/var/run/gammu.pid"
```

Have a nice day